# How To get the custom field value in DNN

Tags: c#, module, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I made 3 different custom field in my DNN portal and I was wondering how would I be able to get the value of the the custom field by integrating a module for that. Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your module, you can get the value of the custom profile field for the current user using this code:

```
User.Profile.GetPropertyValue("CustomFieldName");
```